# Formatting bibliographic names in TUSTEP

Tags: bibliography

I have a large bibliography in the following forms:

```
Lastname, Firstname [optional Middlename]: Title
Lastname1, Firstname1 [optional Middlename1]; Lastname2, Firstname2 [optional Middlename2]: Title
```

I need to automatically convert this into the following form in a TUSTEP session:

```
Firstname [optional Middlename] LASTNAME: Title
Firstname1 [opt. Middlename1] LASTNAME1; Firstname2 [opt. Middlename2] LASTNAME2: Title
```

I could easily run the change on single author names with the instruction `a,,,-{\A}{00}{&a}, {\A}{00}{&a}:-{+5=}{+6=} {+1=}{+2+}:-`, but how can I also execute the change on bibliographic entries with multiple author names in a single pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a,,,-{00}{&a},{00}{!}[;:]-{+3=} {+1+}{+4=}-` should do the trick.
Your instruction did not catch middlenames, that's why the `{!}` was used, catching any kind of ASCII-Symbol including whitespace. And `[;:]` means either colon or semi-colon.

By the way: Not every surname actually starts with an uppercase letter (consider de,von , vaan,t' etc.).

Comment: Your answer pointed me to the right direction, but it was not handling spaces correctly. I got ` FirstnameLASTNAME` instead of `Firstname LASTNAME`. A little editing shows that this here should work: `a,,,-{00}{&a}, {00}{!}[;:]-{+4=} {+1+}{+5=}-`

Comment: Yeah ... did copy by hand and missed typing the space.

Comment: You can edit your answer, so people won't have to look into the comments for the actually working solution